search the content in json files use Azure Data Factory
How do you query the content in JSON files using Azure Data Factory?  I want to filter any JSON files that contain criteria "code":"B" in markings>document>code and "date":"2020-01-01" in metadata>publication date>date. If there is a match, transfers the json files to another storage.
sample json:
{
   "record":{
       "ns":"mra",
       "type":"REC",
       "record":{
           "ns":"rec",
           "id":1001,
           "markings":{
               "document":{
                   "ns":"rec",
                   "code":"B"
               }
            }
       }
  },
  "metadata": { 
      "an": "0002641",
      "markings":{
         "record":{
            "distribution":{
                 
            }
         }   
     },
    "publication date:":{
        "date":"2020-01-01"
    }
  }
}   


Can you provide what you have tried so far? And is the structure of all JSON files same? And what is the source here? Blob? Also are you using Data flow for this?

the structure of all JSON files are same in the blob storage.   I know how to copy activity to copy all the json files to other storage The source and sink datasets are each a normal azure blob storage.  But not knowing how to do query or data flow.

As your source files are in a single folder in Storage account, you can try the below approach to achieve your requirement.
Use Dataflow to get the list of Json file names which satisfies this condition.
Create JSON dataset and only give the path till your folder in the dataset and don't give any name in the filename of the dataset.
In the source of the dataflow, give this dataset and use wild card file path *.json and give a name for the Column to store file name like below.

Next, use filter transformation to set the filter condition. Give the below dynamic expression to filter out the required record.
iif(hasPath('record.record.markings.document.code')&&(hasPath('metadata.{publication date:}.date')),(record.record.markings.document.code=='B')&&(metadata.{publication date:}.date=='2020-01-01'),toBoolean('false'))


This will give the result like below. The records and the file names will be filtered out.

Now, use a select transformation to remove the extra columns apart from filename column.
To send this column data to pipeline, use sink cache.

In the pipeline, add a dataflow activity and set the Logging level to None and uncheck the First row only option of Sink properties in the dataflow activity.
Run the pipeline and it will give the required Json file names in the dataflow output like below.

You need to pass this array to a For loop and use copy activity with parameterized datasets for the file names and copy each file to its target in each iteration.
Add a For-each activity after dataflow activity and give the below expression to pass the above array to for loop.
@activity('<Data flow activity name>').output.runStatus.output.<sink_name>.value


I don't see uncheck First row only in Sink properties all I see options "Run in parallel" and "Continue after sink error."

First set the logging level to None. Go to Sink properties -> uncheck First row only there.

First In the dataflow sink, select cache sink and click on write to activity output. Now, come back to dataflow activity, it will show First row only option under Sink properties after setting the logging level to None.


I couldn't see the First row uncheck option of Sink properties

First In the dataflow sink, select cache sink and click on write to activity output. Now, come back to dataflow activity, it will show First row only option under Sink properties after setting the logging level to None.
